# Mapping an Interval Column to NpgsqlTimeSpan

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

What is the correct way to map a table column of type interval in NPgSql in Entity Framework Core 2?

**Here is the table:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.gap_set
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('gap_set_id_seq'::regclass),
  "left" interval NOT NULL,
  "right" interval NOT NULL,
  avg_time_to_maturity double precision NOT NULL,
  avg_interval interval NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT gap_set_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

**I am using this code:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using NpgsqlTypes;

namespace LarcNet.DAL.Entities
{
    [Table("maturity_sectors", Schema = "public")]
    public partial class GapSet
    {
        [Key, Column("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Column("left", TypeName="interval")]
        public NpgsqlTimeSpan Left { get; set; }

        [Column("right", TypeName="interval")]
        public NpgsqlTimeSpan Right { get; set; }

        [Column("avg_time_to_maturity")]
        public double AverageTimeToMaturity { get; set; }

        [Column("avg_interval", TypeName="interval")]
        public NpgsqlTimeSpan AverageInterval { get; set; }

        [Column("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using LarcNet.DAL.Entities;

namespace LarcNet.DAL.Context
{
        private readonly string m_ConnectionString;
        public DbSet<GapSet> GapSetSet { get; set; }
        public LarcContext(string connectionString)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));
            }
            m_ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_ConnectionString))
            {
                builder.UseNpgsql(m_ConnectionString);
            }
        }
    }
}
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using LarcNet.Contracts;
using LarcNet.Contracts.DataObjects.Communication;
using LarcNet.Contracts.DataObjects.Communication.Requests;
using LarcNet.Contracts.DataObjects.Communication.Responses;
using LarcNet.DAL.Context;
using LarcNet.DAL.Entities;

namespace LarcNet.ConsoleClient
{
    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                    using (var context = new LarcContext("server=127.0.0.1;userid=gadnio;database=mes_sample;Timeout=120;Command Timeout=120;Max Auto Prepare=1000;Auto Prepare Min Usages=1;Application Name=larc;"))
                    {
                        var list = context.GapSetSet.ToList();
                        foreach (var item in list)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Gap Interval: Id={2} Left={0}, Right={1}", item.Left, item.Right, item.Id);
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**It doesn't work, throwing errors instead:**

> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception occurred while reading
>   a database value. The expected type was 'NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlTimeSpan'
>   but the actual value was of type 'System.Double'. --->
>   System.InvalidCastException: Can't cast database type float8 to
>   NpgsqlTimeSpan    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.d__102`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.d__98`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , DbDataReader )    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.ThrowReadValueException[TValue](Exception
>   exception, Object value, IPropertyBase property)    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , DbDataReader )    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactory.Create(DbDataReader
>   dataReader)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean
>   buffer)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState
>   state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__17`2.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1
>   enumerable)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)    at LarcNet.ConsoleClient.MainClass.Main(String[] args) in
>   /data/wirk/repository/web_controller/larc-net2/LarcNet.ConsoleClient/Program.cs:line
>   26

I have tried mapping the column to double, float and TimeSpan fields, all to no avail.